# love2D error: unpack expected table got userdata

Tags: lua, love2d, lua-userdata

When I attempt to unpack this table to call on the images, the program returns the error  "bad argument to unpack (table expected got userdata)"

```
textures = {love.graphics.newImage("image.png"),
      love.graphics.newImage("image.png"),
      love.graphics.newImage("image.png"),
      love.graphics.newImage("image.png"),
      }
```

This is the table I am using

```
  drawScreenLineTexture[x] = {unpack(textures[map[mapX][mapY]])}
if side == 1 then
  drawScreenLineTexture[x][1] = drawScreenLineTexture[x][1] / 2
  drawScreenLineTexture[x][2] = drawScreenLineTexture[x][2] / 2
  drawScreenLineTexture[x][3] = drawScreenLineTexture[x][3] / 2
end
```

This is where I attempt to unpack the table

Comment: `love.graphics.newImage()` returns an userdata.  Why are you expecting loaded image to be a table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to unpack the table textures:

```
textures = {love.graphics.newImage("image.png"),
      love.graphics.newImage("image.png"),
      love.graphics.newImage("image.png"),
      love.graphics.newImage("image.png"),
      }
```

you have to write `unpack(textures)`, not `unpack(textures[map[mapX][mapY])` as `textures[map[mapX][mapY]` is obviously not the table `textures` but one of its sub-elements which happes to be of type userdata.